# Httparchive - BigQuery how to get median bytesTotal per year from 2010-2014

Tags: mysql, database, statistics, google-bigquery

I am currently writing my bachelor theses about web performance and refer to some statistic on httparchive. As I would like to have a nice graph from 2010 to 2014 about bytesTotal, bytesCss and so on I tried to get the data out of BigQuery. The queries do work, but I am getting some results which do not fit to the graphics over at httparchive.org

[image: HttpArchive]

My goal is to have one value for bytesTotal 2010, one for 2011, one for 2012 and so on.

So I tried it with something like this:

```
SELECT NTH(50, quantiles(bytesTotal,101)) TOTAL_med, NTH(50, quantiles(bytesHtmlDoc,101))
HTMLDOC_med FROM [httparchive:runs.2010_11_15_pages], [httparchive:runs.2010_11_29_pages],
[httparchive:runs.2010_12_16_pages], [httparchive:runs.2010_12_28_pages];


SELECT AVG(bytesTotal) TOTAL_med, AVG(bytesHtmlDoc) HTMLDOC_med FROM [httparchive:runs.2010_11_15_pages],
[httparchive:runs.2010_11_29_pages], [httparchive:runs.2010_12_16_pages],
[httparchive:runs.2010_12_28_pages];
```

So medians would be nice, but if they do not work average is fine.

May somebody help me?

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem you're seeing is? The queries you're using look correct (you might want to pre-filter null values, if they exist).

Comment: If I run a query for the median values for 2014_12_15 I get 1211kb as result for bytesTotal... on httparchive it's around 1900kb. So I am asking myself where those extra 700kb come from. Even if httparchive queries for average and not for median 700kb difference should be a little to much.

Comment: do you know how the httparchive numbers were produced?

Comment: Sadly no, but it should the average or median I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it.
Hope you find it useful.

```
SELECT NTH(50, quantiles(bytesTotal)) MedianBytesTotal
FROM [httparchive:runs.2010_12_28_pages], [httparchive:runs.2012_12_15_pages],
[httparchive:runs.2013_12_15_pages], [httparchive:runs.2014_12_15_pages];
```

I got the result as:- MedianBytesTotal -- 1074357

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that wasn't what i wanted. :-) I'd like to have the MedianBytes for each year seperate. But the problem is, that the results differ so much compared to the graph on httparchive (see screenshot above).

Comment: I guess you could do a group by, no? do the tables have a date or something? I would do either multiple queries, with a range for every year, or do a group by with "year" if there's one.